# how to get iterate a date time list to get year

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I want to print only years with the following code, But it seems to error prone, I tried and asked many times but didn't get correct

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('Meteorite_Landings.csv')
a = str(data["year"])
print a
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    b=[datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in a]
    print b
```

I am getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/shiv/Desktop/new_date_times.py", line 9, in 
>       b=[datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in a]   File "C:\Python27\lib_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
>       (data_string, format)) ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'

[image]

[image]

Comment: `a` is a string. If you iterate over it, you'll get characters at a time. I'm not familiar with pandas, but what type is `data`? Try iterating over `data["year"]` directly without casting it to a string.

Comment: Posting a sample of the csv file would be a huge help here. Also as @L3viathan has pointed out, you have converted `a` to a str explicitly so iterating over it is just giving you one character at a time to pass into strptime.

Comment: you should also post here a part or the relevant par of the CSV, other wise it's quite hard to guess what the correct format will be.

Comment: You are also iterating twice: once with the for loop and once with the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this solution, which doesn't deviate much from yours:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('Meteorite_Landings.csv')

for i, val in enumerate(data["year"]):
    try:
        b = datetime.strptime(val, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year
        print b
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

This prints the years. The reason for the try-except thing is that [the dataset you're probably using](https://data.nasa.gov/Space-Science/Meteorite-Landings/gh4g-9sfh) is not complete and contains some NANs (?).

Answer (score 2):

Without the csv file you are trying to read I can't be 100% sure but it looks like you are trying to convert the 'year' column to a datetime, then extract the year from that. Are you sure the column you want is called 'year'? Are you sure every single row has a value in that column? Are you sure every single value in that column follows the exact same format, and that it is the format you use in strptime? It seems odd to me that a column named "year" would contain the whole date. Posting a sample of the csv file would be a huge help here. Making some assumptions about the above questions I have come up with the following code modified from your sample.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv('Meteorite_Landings.csv')

b=[datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in data["year"]]

print b
```

Comment: I edited the post. might be use full but above one is giving error             b=[datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in data["year"]]
TypeError: must be string, not float

Comment: @HariRama Can you post the first few rows of the csv file? As text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a different approach to solve your problem? You are reading a CSV with pandas and then iterating over it. This is horribly slow, and has the disadvantage of not using Pandas API. Instead read the file like this:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv('Meteorite_Landings.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Note you have to adapt the string format to your proper one.
Now you will have a column your date frame with the date, and you can directly access the `year`, as in this example:

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: obj = datetime.datetime.now()

In [3]: obj.year
Out[3]: 2016
```